# ngClass wrong answer

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class, angular-ng-class

After going through a lot of questions , I have decided to ask this...
The angular [ngClass] is working weird on the values for 10 , 24 , 100 . I don't know the reason behind it . Hoping you could all may help...

```
<div class="clearfix table-responsive mt-5">
      <table id="data_upload1" class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover selectParent">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="pointer">Obs</th>
              <th class="pointer">Date</th>
              <th class="pointer">Price</th>
              <th class="pointer">% Change</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <ng-container *ngFor="let price of priceList">
                            <tr> 
                                <td >{{price.serial}}</td>
                                <td >{{price.period}} </td>
                                <td ><input autofocus (blur)="updateValue($event, price.price)" type="text"
                                      [value]="value"  [(ngModel)] = "price.price" placeholder = ""   /></td>
                                <td [ngClass]="price.change >= price.hold  ? 'red': 'greenn'">{{price.change}} </td>
                            </tr>
              </ng-container> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add_user_submit" class="btn btn-blue1 center-block">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the JSON format from backend

```
0:{id: 101, price: 40, period: "2018-02-01", hold: "10", change: "n.a."}
1:{id: 102, price: 42, period: "2018-03-01", hold: "10", change: "5.00"}
2:{id: 103, price: 43, period: "2018-04-01", hold: "10", change: "2.38"}
length:3
```

The ngClass chooses wrong class on values like 10 , 100 , 24  Instead of greenn its showing the background in red color .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
price.change >= price.hold
```

You're comparing two strings.

If you want to compare two numbers, I suggest you change your data to

```
0:{id: 101, price: 40, period: "2018-02-01", hold: 10, change: null}
1:{id: 102, price: 42, period: "2018-03-01", hold: 10, change: 5.00}
2:{id: 103, price: 43, period: "2018-04-01", hold: 10, change: 2.38}
```

And your comparison to

```
price.change && price.change >= price.hold
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Given none of condition is satify. and you are comparing two strings. If you want to compare two number please use "+" in above your string.

Like this : convert string to number : 
[ngClass]="(+price.change) >= (price.hold == 'n.a.' ? 0 : (+price.hold))  ? 'red': 'greenn'"

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let price of priceList"> 
      <td >{{price.serial}}</td>
      <td >{{price.period}} </td>
      <td ><input autofocus type="text" [(ngModel)] = "price.price" placeholder = ""   /></td>
      <td [ngClass]="(+price.change || 0) >= (+price.hold || 0) ? 'red': 'greenn'">{{price.change}} </td>
  </tr>
```

> `(+price.change || 0)` this will convert the string to number and in
>   case the conversion has failed if the value not valid number we will
>   get the 0 value as fallback

I Think you don't need to use `[value]="value"` and `(blur)="updateValue($event, price.price)` this what ngModel will do